# Make multiple Textboxes visible or invisible using for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

In my form I've 50 textboxes in `visible=false` state, when a user enter particular number , those many textboxes should be displayed and the remaining textboxes should remain in `visible false` state.

Comment: "enter particular numb" on what?

Comment: Having 50 invisible text-boxes is a bad idea in any case.

Comment: "enter particular numb" means User input    Ex:if user enters 2 then only 2 textbox should be visible and remaining 48 should be invisible

Comment: What do you mean "those many " should be visible ?

Comment: those many means 'a number entered by a user'

Comment: Just write each `TextBox` with an `id` attribute in view and then call `$('#txt_id').hide()` and `$('#txt_id').show()` jquery functions to control them:)

Comment: @Deepa : I mean user input on which control? Dropdown, another textbox , type on textbox then click button, or what? Maybe you can use client side scripting (like AmirHossein Mehrvarzi's comment) than server side scripting like C#.

Answer (score 1):

Should end up looking something like this:

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    var textbox = control as TextBox;
    if (var != null) textbox.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: This will make all textboxes visible. OP wants to be able to regulate the number of visible ones based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop throug all textbox controls like this:

```
foreach (Control item in this.form1.Controls)
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText tbx = item as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText;
    if (tbx!= null)
    {
        if(tbx.Text == "some text")
             tbx.Visible = false; // or true how ever you want it
        else
             tbx.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

So if tbx is not null, item is textbox, actually:

```
 <input type="text"/>
```

You can do this same trick with other HtmlControls.
Change form1 to that form you, which controls you want to loop through.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your control inside a Asp.net Panel Control.

```
 int counter = 0;
        int numberOfTextBoxtoShow = 4; // set by user
        foreach (Control c in Panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                if (counter < numberOfTextBoxtoShow)
                {
                    c.Visible = true;
                    counter++;
                }
                else c.Visible = false;
            }
       }
```